# FastReport - How to displaying data in the form of table?

Tags: delphi, tabular, fastreport

How can i display data in the form of table in the `FastReport` ?

**Edit**

I mean ,I want to create a report like this : (with tabular format).

[image]

Comment: And where exactly would you like us to begin? Please divulge more of what you have tried and how exactly it doesn't achieve what you want to see. With 76 questions asked on StackOverflow we shouldn't have to ask you for details any more, you should already know nobody can give a reasonable answer without it. At least I do assume you do not expect us to repeat any documentation or sample codes from FastReport here?

Comment: But I think this question is totally clear for somebody who works with `FastReport`.

Comment: Anyway , I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible using `Framing` Property of Memos.

Comment: Kermia, your questions was not clear, do you want to build the table with data as the image, or just you need to draw lines for data as table?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use FR wizard

from FR File menu > new > Standard report wizard

when you reach the "Layout" page, choose tabular from layout then OK

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to build the grid yourself. Here's a bit of code that builds a grid layout to get you started. You will need to adjust the column widths and add the formatting code (memo.frame) to get your desired look.

```
procedure CreateHeader(frxDataset: TfrxDBDataSet; Page: TfrxReportPage);
var
  i: Integer;
  X, Y, ThisWidth: Extended;
  HeaderMemo: TfrxCustomMemoView;
  Column: TcxGridDBColumn;
begin
  Band := TfrxPageHeader.Create(Page);
  Band.CreateUniqueName;
  Band.SetBounds(0, 0, 0, fr01cm * 7);
  Band.Height := edtHeightHeader.Value;

  HeaderMemo := CreateMemo(Band);
  HeaderMemo.SetBounds(0, 0, PageWidth, 0);

  // Set memo style
  // Or just add a frame HeaderMemo.Frame....
  HeaderMemo.Style := 'Header line';

  X := 0;
  Y := 0;

  Memo := CreateMemo(Band);
  Memo.SetBounds(0, Y, X, fr01cm * 6);
  Memo.Height := Band.Height - 1;

  for i := 0 to pred(frxDataset.Fields.Count) do
  begin
    ThisWidth := 100;

    Memo := CreateMemo(Band);
    Memo.SetBounds(X, Y, ThisWidth, fr01cm * 6);

    Memo.Text := frxDataset.Fields[i].FieldName;

    // Set memo style
    // Or just add a frame HeaderMemo.Frame....
    Memo.Style := 'Header';

    Memo.Height := Band.Height - 1;

    X := X + ThisWidth;
  end;

  HeaderMemo.Height := Band.Height;
end;

procedure CreateFastReportDataBand(frxDataset: TfrxDBDataSet; Page: TfrxReportPage);
var
  i: Integer;
  X, Y, ThisWidth: Extended;
begin
  Band := TfrxMasterData.Create(Page);
  Band.CreateUniqueName;
  Band.SetBounds(0, CurY, 0, 0);
  Band.Height := edtHeightData.Value;

  TfrxMasterData(Band).frxDataset := frxDataset;

  X := 0;
  Y := 0;

  for i := 0 to pred(frxDataset.Fields.Count) do
  begin
    ThisWidth := 100;

    Memo := CreateMemo(Band);
    Memo.SetBounds(X, Y, ThisWidth, fr01cm * 5);
    Memo.Dataset := frxDataset;
    Memo.DataField := frxDataset.Fields[i].FieldName;

    // Set memo style
    // Or just add a frame HeaderMemo.Frame....
    Memo.Style := 'Data';

    Memo.Height := Band.Height - 1;

    X := X + ThisWidth;
  end;
end;
```

It should work ok, but I've not had a chance to test since decoupling it from my application.